# SharePoint Online OneDrive/Team Site determine default document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, site-collection

Is it possible to determine which is the default document library for a site collection using CSOM. ie when you go to OneDrive for Business the default is 'Documents' is there a flag to determine this is the default I noticed when you go to view site contents and you have a multiple libraries documents can not be removed. Is there flag for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked through the properties to see what distinguishes this list to other lists is the BaseTemplate = 700 whereas other documents lists created are 101